# Android - View Model Test - Kotlin - Hilt - Clean Architecture

Tags: android, android-studio, unit-testing, kotlin, clean-architecture

I am still pretty new at this. Kind of lost on how to test this view model with flows and clean architecture. Any advice is very much appreciated!

```
@HiltViewModel
class CoinListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getAllCoinsUseCase: GetListOfCoinsUseCaseImpl
): ViewModel() {

    private val _state = mutableStateOf(CoinsListState()) // not exposed because mutable
    val state: State<CoinsListState> = _state // expose this to composable because immutable

    init {
        getData()
    }

    // method to call the use case - put the data in the state object - then display state in the ui
    private fun getData(){

        getAllCoinsUseCase().onEach { resourceResult ->

            when(resourceResult){
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    _state.value = CoinsListState(isLoading = true)
                }
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    _state.value = CoinsListState(coins = resourceResult.data ?: emptyList())
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    _state.value = CoinsListState(
                        error = resourceResult.message ?: "Unexpected Error"
                    )
                }
            }
        }.launchIn(viewModelScope) // must launch in coroutine scope because using a flow
    }
}
```